# Adding template block to another block dynamically for a module

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

I'm trying to add a template block to my footer block in the product view (only), the product detail page. I've tried the following in the catalog.xml layout file, but with no luck:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
  ...
  <reference name="footer">
      <block type="core/template" name="uniqueName" template="catalog/product/mytemplate.phtml" />
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

and

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
  ...
  <reference name="footer">
      <block type="core/template" name="uniqueName">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/product/mytemplate.phtml</template></action>
      </block>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

I was able to put the template block into the `content` block using the latter method the same way, `<reference name="content">`, so I don't understand why this isn't working. It seems like I'm not referencing the footer properly.. I see in the page.xml file the footer being created added as `<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">`. Can somebody help me figure this out? Much appreciated!

Comment: Where are you calling echo $this->getChildHtml('uniqueName') ?

Comment: Yes, I actually just noticed that is my problem. The footer template isn't calling `$this->getChildren();`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `page.xml`, take a look at the layout update xml fragment that instantiates the `content` block object

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
```

The `content` block is `core/text_list` block.  The `core/text_list` blocks automatically render their child blocks (i.e. they're a contain block for a list of text blocks).  The `core/text_list` alias resolves to `Mage_Core_Block_Text_List`, take a look at this classes rendering method to see why appending things to your content block works.

Now, take a look at the layout update XML fragment that instantiates the footer block.

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
```

The foot block is **not** a text list block.  It's a `page/html_footer` block, which is a template block.  You can determine this by looking at the class that the `page/html_footer` block inherits from

```
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

Template blocks **do not** automatically render all their child blocks.  Instead, inside the block's template, you must explicitly render a child with a call to

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('block_name');
```

So when you say

```
<reference name="footer">
     <block type="core/template" name="uniqueName" template="catalog/product/mytemplate.phtml" />
</reference>
```

you're telling Magento to insert a block named `uniqueName` as a child block of the `footer` block.  However, in order to **render** the block, the footer's template must call

```
$this->getChildHtml('uniqueName')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the block template (footer block in my case) that you are trying to add your block to is calling your child block that you have added in your layout xml..

footer.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('uniqueName'); ?>
```